Solving $x-5\lfloor x\rfloor\;\geq\;1$. Am I wrong?
On my Algebra exam, I got this question:
$$x-5\lfloor x\rfloor\;\geq\;1$$
My teacher got a solution like $x\in\{..., -9,-5,-1\}$, and I got this $x\in(-\infty,0)$. I think he is not correct.
My answer. I'm not sure if this part is correct:
$$x+4\;\geq\;1+5\lfloor x \rfloor+4 \quad\Rightarrow\quad x+4\;\geq\;5\lfloor x+1\rfloor \tag1$$ And from here, it must follow $$\frac15(x+4) \;\geq\;\lfloor x+1\rfloor \tag2$$ This is only possible when $x\in\{..., -9,-5,-1\}.$
My teacher's answer. $\frac15(x+4)$ is an integer to apply the correct theorem in inequations, so:
$x+4$ is multiple of $5$, and then solve like normal.
But I think the analysis is incorrect to say "must be true in order to use this theorem", when in $$x+4\;\geq\;5\lfloor x+1 \rfloor$$ we can say that it doesn't matter if $x$ is an integer or not; we can give it $x=n+k$, with $n$ a integer and $k$ between $0$ and $1$ and make it more general, right?
Thank you in advance.

Do you mean $x\in (-\infty,0)$? If so I agree with your result. The fact that $x=-0.5$ implies $x-5\lfloor x\rfloor=-0.5-5(-1)=4.5>1$ is a counterexample to the proposed solution. The proposed solution is not even correct if we restrict to integers: If $x$ is an integer, then $\lfloor x \rfloor =x$ and thus the inequation becomes $x-5x=-4x\geq 1$ which is true for any negative integer.

$x < 0$  A quick sketch of the curve $y = x - 5\lfloor x\rfloor$ might help you make your argument.  The curve is a sort of a saw-tooth that is upward sloping with slope 1 when x is not an integer and steps down by 5 at every integer.

The correct solution is $x \in (-\infty, 0)$. I don't even know what your teacher could have meant by saying $(x+4) / 5$ is an integer, he must have got confused with something. The manipulations you performed are valid.

Having read through your post, it seems that maybe your teacher had specified that your answer must refer to the integer values of $x$ which would satisfy the inequation. Is this correct? If so, while your answer may be true, it isn't exactly what the teacher was looking for unfortunately...

If we are only looking for integer values the teacher may be correct but that's a ridiculous interpretation.  If $x \in \mathbb Z$ then $[x]=x$ and the question is $x-5x \ge 1$ which is not an interesting question and avoids EVERYTHING that is relevant about the floor function.  What's the point of a floor function if you just assume everything is an integer anyway?  Not to appear too crotchety, but I'm chalking this one up to yet another teacher is an idiot.

"another teacher is an idiot" or another student has misread/miscopied a problem, or another little typo has completely altered a problem, or ....

" is an integer to apply the correct theorem in inequations"  In order to apply what theorem?  "But I think the analysis is incorrect to say "must be true in order to use this theorem""  I still don't know which theorem, but saying "A must be true to use a theorem, so it is true" is butt-backwards.  Wanting to use a theorem can't make something magically be true.  It just means if it isn't true, you are up poop-creek and can't use the theorem. Just because you want to use a thereom want make what you need be true.

@GerryMyerson .... or $\lfloor x \rfloor$ was just meant to be brackets and the problem was to solve for $x -5x \ge 1; x\in \mathbb Z$.

I think it's time to raise the question with your teacher, Sebastian, to find out where things flew off the rails.

It looks like someone butchered the question, first paragraph says teacher's solution is $x\in{..., -9,-5,-1}.$, but then your attempt reaches same conclusion...
